# Jquery: Trying to use .before or .after on an HTML string before appending to DOM

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert HTML strings before and after an HTML string before writing the finished string to the DOM. Here's what I have so far:

```
var Hello = '<p id="1234">Hello</p>'; 
var $Hello = $(Hello);
var $HelloGoodbye = $Hello.after('<p>Goodbye</p>');
$('#content').append($HelloGoodbye);
```

The result is that my #content div only gets the Hello fragment appended.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `$Hello` is a reference to the `<p>` element. You are putting the 'Goodbye' `<p>` outside of the first, so the `$Hello` variable remains unaffected. You need some method of grouping the two together if you want to have them in a single variable. Try this:

```
var $hello = $('<div></div>');
$hello.append('<p id="1234">Hello</p>');
$hello.append('<p>Goodbye</p>');
$('#content').append($hello);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3M9Yx/)

Answer (score 0):

If you put Goodbye **after** the element, it is not **in** the element. Why don't you replace

```
var $HelloGoodbye = $Hello.after('<p>Goodbye</p>');
```

with

```
var $HelloGoodbye = $Hello.append('<p>Goodbye</p>');
```

Good luck!

Comment: A `<p>` within a `<p>` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

.after() appends the content to the parent of the selected element. In your case, $Hello is not appended to any element, so .after() has no effect. If you switch the last two lines #content will append "Goodbye too".

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xQZV/1/

​